# How to change animation in the bootstrap slider

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I already googled and found several solutions, but noone fits my needs, so i have to ask here:

I found a website which contains a pretty awesome slider, see here: http://www.lysebu.no/en/hotel. I talk about the 2nd slider on the bottom. The slider itself is easy to build, but i was pretty impressed by the animation changes if you switch to another categorie, so i tried to rebuild it myself, maybe i can use it in future projects. Unfortunally, i have no idea how i can realize the animation change, i can only change the whole animation via CSS, but thats not what i want. My Slider contains 17 images and the structure is like the usual bootstrap slider. My attempt would be to change the CSS-Properties with the .css method of jQuery which looks like this (found the CSS-Code here on SO, just btw):

```
function change_ani() {
    item = $('.carousel .item');

    item.css("-webkit-transition", "opacity: 3s");
    item.css("-moz-transition", "opacity: 3s");
    item.css("-ms-transition", "opacity: 3s");
    item.css("-o-transition", "opacity: 3s");
    item.css("transition", "opacity: 3s");

    $(".carousel .active.left").css("left", 0);
    $(".carousel .active.left").css("opacity", 0);
    $(".carousel .active.left").css("z-index", 2);

    $(".carousel .active.right").css("left", 0);
    $(".carousel .active.right").css("opacity", 0);
    $(".carousel .active.right").css("z-index", 2);

    $(".carousel .active.next").css("left", 0);
    $(".carousel .active.next").css("opacity", 1);
    $(".carousel .active.next").css("z-index", 1);

    $(".carousel .active.prev").css("left", 0);
    $(".carousel .active.prev").css("opacity", 1);
    $(".carousel .active.prev").css("z-index", 1);

}
```

The function gets called here:

```
$("#rooms_div").click(function() {
    showRooms();
    $('#carousel-slider2').carousel(0);
    change_ani();
});
```

"#rooms_div is" the box in the slider which is glowing white at the beginning. Unfortunally, this doesnt work. Im not that familiar with JS or jQuery, so i hope someone got an idea how to solve this problem. It doesnt have to be perfect code, you can give me quick-and-dirty code too, i just want that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Carousel uses the CSS3 animation. If you want to fade, use this as a class.

```
.carousel-fade {
  .carousel-inner {
    .item {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
      -moz-transition-property: opacity;
      -o-transition-property: opacity;
      transition-property: opacity;
    }

    .active {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .active.left,
    .active.right {
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .next.left,
    .prev.right {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  .carousel-control {
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/Rowno/pen/Afykb

Comment: Yes, i know that, i already added a similar code as you can see. The thing is, i want that the slider works like on the page mentioned. So it should just fade when i change my categorie, and thats the problem, i dont know how to "trigger" a css class with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/MABZj/8/)

I guess this is what you want

### code

```
var i = 1;
$('.right').click(function () {
    if (i < $('.box').length) {
        $("#box" + i).animate({
            left: '-50%'
        }, 400, function () {
            var $this = $("#box" + i);
            $this.css('left', '150%')
                .appendTo($('.container'));
        });
        $("#box" + i).next().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 400);
        i++;
    }
});
$('.left').click(function () {

    if (i > 1) {
        $("#box" + i).animate({
            left: '150%'
        }, 400, function () {
            var $this = $("#box" + i);
            $this.css('right', '-150%')
                .appendTo($('.container'));
        });
        $("#box" + i).prev().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 400);
        i--;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps, thank you

Comment: Unfortunally no. My slider is working already, so i can switch between images. The only thing which doesnt work yet is the different transition between other images. Its pretty difficult to explain, on the website i posted above is an example how the slider should work in the end. Its the 2nd one on the bottom.